# How to make auto-increment the cell?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, auto-increment

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqaiM.png) is a screenshot of my excel file.

How to increment **`# of attend classes`** based on *yes* or *no* drop-list.

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have the zero (in G2):

`=COUNTIF(I2:ZZ2,"Yes")`

This will add one for each cell in the given range which matches "Yes".